# JS Classes and OOJS

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, dry

I'm refactoring some code for a side project and I'm really trying to get the hang of doing things from an OO perspective instead of just throwing functions here and variables there.

I have multiple ajax requests and I see some similarities that they share, which is what got me thinking of throwing them in a class. I'm not sure if I should create a separate one for each one which would mean creating a new instance of each one or is one class and one instance good for this scenario?

Finally, some more questions I would really appreciate some expert advice one

- Is it even worth bringing them into classes?
- Every AJAX call is going to have the same methods called from the `xhr` , ie. `.open, .send` etc., object but with different values, how should I handle this in a class to help DRY my code up?

### JS

```
class AJAXRequests {
  constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  deletePostPromise(url, postID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      this.xhr.send(postID);

      this.xhr.onload = () => {
        if (this.xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(this.xhr.statusText);
        }
      };

      this.xhr.onerror = () => {
        reject(this.xhr.statusText);
      };
    });
  }

  submitPost(url, user_id, user_name, content) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.xhr.open('POST', url, true);

      this.xhr.onload = () => {
        if (this.xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(this.xhr.statusText);
        }
      };

      this.xhr.onerror = () => {
        reject(this.xhr.statusText);
      };

      this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      this.xhr.send(user_id, user_name, content);
    });
  }

  returnNewestPost(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      this.xhr.open('GET', url, true);

      this.xhr.onload = () => {
        if (this.xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(this.xhr.response));
        } else {
          reject(this.xhr.statusText);
        }
      };

      this.xhr.onerror = () => {
        reject(this.xhr.statusText);
      };

      this.xhr.send();
    });
  }
}
const ajaxRequests = new AJAXRequests;
```

Honestly, looking at this class I feel like I might've wasted some time refactoring. The only positive from doing this is it will be easier to move this class to its own file to clean my main JS up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not use `class` syntax here. You don't need to create any objects at all here, you'd only call a single method on them anyway. And if you planned to reuse an instance with the same `.xhr`, it looks as if you were going for a singleton `ajaxRequests`. Don't do that.

Just write multiple functions, with helper functions for the parts that are shared. For example:

```
function promiseForXhr(xhr) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(xhr.statusText);
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(xhr.statusText);
    };
  });
}

function deletePostPromise(url, postID) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(postID);
  return promiseforXhr(xhr);
}

function submitPost(url, user_id, user_name, content) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(user_id, user_name, content);
  return promiseforXhr(xhr);
}

function returnNewestPost(url) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
  return promiseforXhr(xhr).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Now if you feel that this is still not dry enough, just use more helper functions. You may either parameterise them or use different functions:

```
function getFormXhr(url) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  return xhr;
}

function deletePostPromise(url, postID) {
  const xhr = getFormXhr(url);
  xhr.send(postID);
  return promiseforXhr(xhr);
}
function submitPost(url, user_id, user_name, content) {
  const xhr = getFormXhr(url);
  xhr.send(user_id, user_name, content);
  return promiseforXhr(xhr);
}
```

or further

```
function getXhrPromise({url, method, headers={}, sendArgs=[]}) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  for (const h in headers)
    xhr.setRequestHeader(h, headers[h]);
  xhr.send(...sendArgs);
  return promiseForXhr(xhr);
}
formRequest(url, ...sendArgs) {
  return {
    url,
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    sendArgs
  };
}

function deletePostPromise(url, postID) {
  return getXhrPromise(formRequest(url, postID));
}
function submitPost(url, user_id, user_name, content) {
  return getXhrPromise(formRequest(url, user_id, user_name, content));
}
function returnNewestPost(url) {
  return getXhrPromise({
    url,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Comment: So what youre saying is creating classes should only be reserved for scenarios where you would need to use multiple methods from the same class instance?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Yes. An object with only a single method to be called has no advantage over a plain function to be called directly.

Comment: That makes sense. So what's the argument against just creating a class that holds all my ajax calls seperated into different methods which would all use the `promiseForXhr(xhr)` function in your first example? Does this just come down to preference? They all belong to the same category, ajax, and have similarities.

Comment: If you want to somehow namespace them, put them in a common "ajax" module from which the functions are exported or put them as methods on an object literal assigned to a "ajax" constant - that's up to your preference. But you don't need multiple object instances of anything, so you don't use `class` syntax.